# Custom Module for PriceRound

Tags: module

I'm building my first custom module and I think i'm almost there except there seems te be a small error in my code. I tried to overwrite two files from Magento Core.

app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Catalog/Product/Helper/Form/Price.php

and

app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Store.php

I created the module folder in app/etc/modules/
With: Vendor_Module.xml

```
<config>
  <modules>
       <Vendor_Module>
           <active>true</active>
           <codePool>local</codePool>
       </Vendor_Module>
   </modules>
</config>
```

I created a directory in app/code/local/Vendor/Module
With:

Block/Price.php

```
<?php
require_once(Mage::getModuleDir('Block','Mage_Adminhtml').DS.'/Catalog/Product/Helper/Form/Price.php');

class Vendor_Module_Block_Price extends Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Catalog_Product_Helper_Form_Price {

/**
 * Override the required function here, 
 * e.g. createAction
 */
public function getEscapedValue($index=null)
    {
        $value = $this->getValue();

        if (!is_numeric($value)) {
            return null;
        }

        return number_format($value, 4, null, '');
    }
}
```

etc/config.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
<modules>
    <Vendor_Module>
        <version>0.0.1</version>
    </Vendor_Module>
</modules>
<global>
    <blocks>
        <Module>
            <class>Atvise_RoundPrices_Block</class>
        </Module>
    </blocks>
    <models>
        <Module>
            <class>Atvise_RoundPrices_Model</class>
        </Module>
    </models>
</global>
</config>
```

Model/Store.php

```
<?php
require_once(Mage::getModuleDir('Model','Mage_Core').DS.'Store.php');

class Vendor_Module_Model_Store extends Mage_Core_Model_Store
{
/**
 * Override the required function here, 
 * e.g. createAction
 */
public function roundPrice($price)
{
    return round($price, 4);
}
}
```

Can you guys help me out for the last bit of code or corrections?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You will need to update your `config.xml` to tell Magento to use your classes and not the originals. For your example I would guess something like the following should work.

```
<global>
    <blocks>
        <adminhtml>
            <rewrite>
                <catalog_product_helper_form_price>Vendor_Module_Block_Price</catalog_product_helper_form_price>
            </rewrite>
        </adminhtml>
    </blocks>
</global>
```

For a bit more about rewriting classes in Magento 1 I would suggest there is plenty of good further reading such as [Inchoo](http://inchoo.net/magento/overriding-magento-blocks-models-helpers-and-controllers/)